# how can I query FeedAttachment body by SOAP API 36

Tags: api, attachment, soap, feeditem

Hi I'd like to download images of feed files. I know how to do it for Attachment in which I just have to run SOQL like `"Select ID, BODY, NAME from ATTACHMENT where ...".` by encoding and decoding the body, I'm able to download attachment.

I'm wondering how can I do it for Feed Attachments.

In SOAP API Developer guide it has an example

```
"SELECT Body, (SELECT RecordId, Title, Type, Value FROM FeedAttachments)
FROM FeedItem
WHERE Id = ..."
```

But I still can't get the Body of the attachment. Could you please help?

Answer (score 2):

These are the following ways you can retrieve the attachment of feed items

`"SELECT Body, (SELECT RecordId, Title, Type, Value FROM FeedAttachments)
FROM FeedItem
WHERE Id = ..."`

Take `RecordId` from above SOQL and pass it as an `Id` of `ContentVersion` like this:

`SELECT Title, Id, VersionData FROM ContentVersion
Id =<RecordId>`

The retrieved `VersionData` returns base64 encoded file data. You can convert it to blob by the use of `EncodingUtil.base64Decode('<VersionData>')`

For more information refer [ContentVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm)